# Assign Event by Event Handler

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, krypton-toolkit, krypton

In my application i am using Krypton Component Factory.

My application i have Ribbon Menu and Some krypton buttons. In krypton buttons i want to assign click event of Ribbon Menu Group Button at run time. The events of Ribbon Menu Group Button Changed Based some condition so i tried like this

```
Dim eventsField = GetType(Component).GetField("events", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
BindingFlags.Instance)
Dim eventHandlerList = eventsField.GetValue(KryptonRibbonGroupButton1)
eventsField.SetValue(KryptonButton1, eventHandlerList)
```

Its not work. The Get Field always return nothing.

Problem: I want add handler of Krypton Button Click event by old ribbon menu button throw coding using the controls name only. Its Possible or not? Its possible how to do it?

am using Vb.Net

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: But my Ribbon menu button changed based on some condition so can not directly set add handler.